# Node.js async call from teplate

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I just started with node.js and this question has an obvious answer for sure, but I can't pull it off.

Lets have a model called `club` with this single method:

```
club.getStaff = function(callback) {
    client.sinter('club-staff:'+club.id, callback);
};
```

So far I managed the application flow through the callbacks, but now I'm stuck in templates. How would I render an async call? I would like to iterate over the `staff` and print it.

I suppose I could call this method before the render and in fact render in it's callback. That feels somewhat wrong. Wastes resources if the method does not need to be called (because of a if in the template of whatever). Also, the *render wrapper* would grow for each new (async) variable introduced.

Comment: use the prototype model. Club.prototype.getStaff = fun... prototypes aren't "instantiated" upon object creation, but available if invoked.

Comment: @FlavorScape Sorry, I fail to see how that would solve it. The issue is that calling `club.getStaff` in template expects async treatment and does not return the value I would like to iterate over. Prototype chain would not make it "blocking", would it?

Comment: What framework are you using?  Express?

Comment: @josh3736 Yep, right, `express` + `jade`.

Comment: no, but you expressed concerns about unneeded memory usage, and that's the only concern i tried to address.

Comment: @FlavorScape Oh thanks, in that case it's a great trick. Seems like I have to rewrite all my models after all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most templating engines, you can't call async functions from your template.

Instead you have to call the async function from your controller, and when it returns, pass the data to the template.

Assuming Express:

```
app.get('/route/', function(req, res) {
    club.getStaff(function(data) {
        res.render('template', data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, that feels unpleasant. Thank you though, finally I will at least be content with this solution knowing it's the only way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

in node you can use [nai](https://github.com/Ournet/nai) for async templates.